# Reverse-proxy to Dockerized REST APIs with Dockerized NGINX

Tags: docker, nginx-reverse-proxy

Please see **follow-up at bottom**

I'm new to NGINX and trying to setup a simple, in-house development Ubuntu server for multiple REST API and SPA apps entry points, so I can learn some NGINX basics.

All the APIs and SPAs I want to serve are dockerized, and each exposes its services (for API) or page (for SPA) on a localhost (the Docker's host) port.

For instance, I have an API at `localhost:60380` and an Angular SPA app at `localhost:4200`, each running in its own Docker container.

I can confirm that these work fine, as I can reach both at their localhost-based URL. Each API also provides a [Swagger](https://swagger.io/) entry point at its URL e.g. `localhost:60380/swagger` (or, more verbosely, `localhost:60380/swagger/index.html`).

I'd now want to have NGINX listening at `localhost:80`, and reverse-proxy requests to each corresponding services, based on the request's URL. To keep things clean, NGINX too is dockerized, i.e. run from a container using the NGINX open source version.

To dockerize NGINX I followed the directions at https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/installing-nginx/installing-nginx-docker/, i.e. I run a container from the `nginx` image, using volumes to point to host's folders for NGINX configuration and static content. I just changed the Docker command, as I had issues in using the mount-based syntax suggested in the documentation (it seems that `/` is not an allowed character, even if I specified the `bind` option; please notice that the following command is executed from `/var`):

```sh
docker run --name mynginx -v $(pwd)/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -v $(pwd)/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf:ro -p 80:80 -d nginx
```

i.e.:

- host `/var/www` => container `/usr/share/nginx/html`;
- host `/var/nginx/conf` => `/etc/nginx`.

As a test, I created a couple of static web sites in the host's folders mapped as the source for the volumes, i.e.:

- `/var/www/site1`
- `/var/www/site2`

Both these folders just have a static web page (`index.html`).

I placed in the host's `/var/nginx/conf` folder a `nginx.conf` file to serve these 2 static webs. This is the configuration I came up with:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  # include imports configuration from a separate file.
  # In this case it imports a types block, mapping each MIME type
  # to a file extension, e.g.:
  # types {
  #   text/html              html htm shtml;
  #   text/css               css;
  #   application/javascript js;
  # ... etc
  # }
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

  # the default type used if no mapping is found in types:
  # here the browser will just download the file.
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # log's format: the 1st parameter is the format's name (main);
  # the second is a series of variables with different values
  # for every request.
  log_format main
    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  # path to the log file and log format's name (main, defined above).
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  # set to on: do not block on disk I/O.
  sendfile on;

  # keep connection alive timeout. As a page usually has a lot of assets,
  # this keeps the connection alive the time required to send them;
  # otherwise, a new connection would be created for each asset.
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  # enable output compression. Recommendation is on.
  gzip on;

  # include all the .conf files under this folder:
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;
  location /site1 {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/site1;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
  location /site2 {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/site2;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

This works fine, and I can browse to these two sites from `localhost/site1` and `localhost/site2`.

I then started one of my dockerized APIs exposed at `localhost:60380`. I added to the NGINX configuration, in the same server block, the following `location`, to reach it at `localhost/sample/api` (and its swagger at `localhost/sample/api/swagger`):

```
  location /sample/api {
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:60380;
  }
```

As this is an ASP.NET Core web API, I used as a starting point the configuration suggested at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1. Apart from some header passing directions, that's not essentially different from the one found e.g. at [How to use nginx to serve a web app on a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965728/how-to-use-nginx-to-serve-a-web-app-on-a-docker-container).

I have then saved the NGINX configuration in the host folder, and signaled NGINX to refresh it with `docker kill -s HUP <mycontainername>`.

Anyway, while I am still able to reach the API at `localhost:60380`, and the two static webs still work, I get a 404 when accessing `localhost/sample/api` or `localhost/sample/api/swagger`.

I tried to add `proxy_redirect http://localhost:60380/ /sample/api/;` as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/801725/nginx-config-for-restful-api-behind-proxy), but nothing changes.

Could you suggest what I'm doing wrong?

### Update 1

I tried added the trailing `/` to the URI but I'm still getting 404. If this works for Kaustubh (see the answer below), that's puzzling for me as I'm still on 404; or maybe we did something different. Let me recap also for the benefit of other unexperienced readers like me:

1. prepare the host:

```sh
cd /var

mkdir nginx
cd nginx
mkdir conf
cd ..

mkdir www
cd www
mkdir site1
cd ..
mkdir site2
cd ..
```

Then add an `index.html` page in each of the folders `/var/www/site1`, `/var/www/site2`, and the below `nginx.conf` under `var/nginx/conf`:

```
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
  # include imports configuration from a separate file.
  # In this case it imports a types block, mapping each MIME type
  # to a file extension, e.g.:
  # types {
  #   text/html              html htm shtml;
  #   text/css               css;
  #   application/javascript js;
  # ... etc
  # }
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

  # the default type used if no mapping is found in types:
  # here the browser will just download the file.
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  # log's format: the 1st parameter is the format's name (main);
  # the second is a series of variables with different values
  # for every request.
  log_format main
    '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

  # path to the log file and log format's name (main, defined above).
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

  # set to on: do not block on disk I/O.
  sendfile on;

  # keep connection alive timeout. As a page usually has a lot of assets,
  # this keeps the connection alive the time required to send them;
  # otherwise, a new connection would be created for each asset.
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  # enable output compression. Recommendation is on.
  gzip on;

  # include all the .conf files under this folder:
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location /site1 {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/site1;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
  location /site2 {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html/site2;
    index index.html index.htm;
  }
  # https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-3.1
  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57965728/how-to-use-nginx-to-serve-a-web-app-on-a-docker-container
  # https://serverfault.com/questions/801725/nginx-config-for-restful-api-behind-proxy
  location /sample/api {
    # proxy_redirect http://localhost:60380/ /sample/api/;
    proxy_pass_header Server;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:60380/;
  }
  # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  }
}
```

2. `docker run --name mynginx -v $(pwd)/www:/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -v $(pwd)/nginx/conf:/etc/nginx/conf:ro -p 80:80 -d --net=host nginx` (notice the added `--net=host`)
3. navigate to `localhost/site1` and `localhost/site2`: this works.
4. start your API at `localhost:60380` (this is the API port in my sample). I can see it working at `localhost:60380` and its swagger page at `localhost:60380/swagger`.
5. navigate to `localhost/sample/api`: 404. Same for `localhost/sample/api/swagger/index.html` or any other URI with this prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate this at my end as much as possible. I was able to get it working only after I used `--net=host` in the `docker run` command for nginx. Below is the command I used. I had to use this option because the nginx docker container was not able to connect to my api docker container

`$ docker run --name nginx -v $(pwd):/usr/share/nginx/html:ro -v $(pwd)/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro -p 80:80 --net=host -id nginx`

`/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf` is the default virtual host configuration in nginx that displays the `Welcome to nginx page`.

I changed it to below config:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    # For static files
    location / {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }

    # For reverse_proxy
    location /sample/api {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/;
    }
}
```

According to this [answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite) a trailing slash after the port no should fix this.

I have tested the same at my end and it works.

Comment: Thank you very much, but as for the location, my scenario is just that I want localhost/sample/api to become localhost:60380; AFAIK, a request localhost/cadmus/api matching server "localhost" and location prefix "/cadmus/api" would be rewritten as "localhost:60380", and that's all; the API just lives in a specific port of the localhost server, it has no path. Instead, I suppose the --net param has to be added; I tried with it, but it still does not work.

Comment: I think this might be what you are looking for : `https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite`

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately, it seems I'm still doing something wrong. See my updated post above.